# Why msfconsole is always showing "please answer yes or no"

Tags: osx, metasploit

[image: This is my error]

As you can see, i installed metasploit and `cd` to `/opt/metasploit-framework/bin`, then type `./msfconsole`.

According to the prompt shows, i tried to type `yes`, but it failed...
It is still showing the prompt `answer yes or no`...and won't stop until I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to block it.

What shall i do to make it right?
(The OS is Mac-OSX)

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 1):

The script `msfconsole` may be a `bash` script.  `bash` has a `-p` option for its `read` built-in that displays a prompt to the user.

However, the error message `no coprocess` is printed by `zsh` whose `read` also has a `-p` option but with a totally different meaning. This means that the script is being executed by the wrong shell, and that the `read` fails in the function `check_path` which makes the function complain about not getting the correct input from the user.

So, to fix this, make sure `msfconsole` has the correct `#!`-line at the very top, pointing to the appropriate shell interpreter (probably `bash`) on your system.

Or, run the script with an explicit interpreter, like

```
bash ./msfconsole
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nano .zshrc
```

Add this

```
export PATH=/opt/metasploit-framework/bin:$PATH
```

Then run a new window.

```
msfconsole
```

I tried this way.

[image: I tried this way.]